# Restart MySql Server using Service mysql status > /dev/null command not found

Tags: mysql, centos7

Mysql server goes down in few days or weeks but at night. I tried search this forum and found this command

```
*/5 * * * * service mysql status > /dev/null || service mysql start
```

This check status in every five minute and if not work, It attempt to restart but I got email saying command not found like this in email

`/bin/sh: service: command not found`

I'm using

- CentOs7
- CWP 7

One more thing is when MySql is down I don't need to restart it, I just have to login to admin panel It shows error first then after refreshing everything works fine even MySql start again.

[Added Cron Command in CWP7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEKBW.jpg)

Comment: You should find out the root cause why your MySQL server is failing instead of adding band-aid to hide the problems.

Comment: Actually it seems low memory and CPU I have increased it. But some times still face issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` doesn't have the user (esp. root) PATH environment by default.

Try by giving the whole path

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/service mysql status > /dev/null || /usr/sbin/service mysql start
```

If that doesn't work (CentOS 7 is using systemd), try to replace `service` with `/bin/systemctl`

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/systemctl status mysql > /dev/null || /bin/systemctl start mysql
```

Note that `systemctl` takes the command first, then the service.

See https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-beginners-guide-to-systemd-service-units/

> In previous versions of RHEL, the service utility is used to stop and start services. In RHEL 7, the systemctl utility provides an equivalent set of subcommands.

Some distribs (like Ubuntu) provide a convenient `service` script that does the `systemctl` commands under the hood - not sure if CentOS 7 provided the utility.

Comment: First command seems work but it shows me ```Starting mysql (via systemctl):  [  OK  ]``` Does it restarting Mysql in every 5 min ? or First check if it's down then it restart

Comment: If you do `restart`, it restarts... It's better to check first if it's already running. You can also ensure mysql restarts after a crash (that can be risky) check this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples (see the systemd part, at the end)